# Overwriting class object due to string parsing issue

Tags: c#, list, class, object, text-files

I am trying to read a fixed width text file and store each element to a class object.  Each row in the text file needs to be checked for which parsing action must be performed.  Rows 1000 and 1001 each need to be parsed differently and rows 1002-1004 use the same parsing action.  I am reading the file and parsing correctly, but when I add elements to the class object the object gets overwritten in each "if" statement.  Then when the object is added to a list the list contains empty lines.  I feel like I am taking the wrong approach.  I am new to C# and I apologize if this has been answered, but after many hours of searching I cannot find a solution.  Below is the text file and code.

1000  AttributeOne  AttributeTwo
1001  123456.000000       AttributeFour
1002  1234.0 2345.0 3456.0 
1003  1234.0 2345.0 3456.0 
1004  1234.0 2345.0 3456.0
1000  AttributeOne  AttributeTwo
1001  456789.000000       AttributeFour
1002  1234.0 2345.0 3456.0 
1003  1234.0 2345.0 3456.0 
1004  1234.0 2345.0 3456.0
1000  AttributeOne  AttributeTwo
1001  234567.000000       AttributeFour
1002  1234.0 2345.0 3456.0 
1003  1234.0 2345.0 3456.0 
1004  1234.0 2345.0 3456.0
1000  AttributeOne  AttributeTwo
1001  345678.000000       AttributeFour
1002  1234.0 2345.0 3456.0 
1003  1234.0 2345.0 3456.0 
1004  1234.0 2345.0 3456.0

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
namespace list_question
{    
    public class someObject
    {
        //Line 1
        public int Line1_ID;
        public string Line1_Attribute1;
        public string Line1_Attribute2;
        //Line 2
        public int Line2_ID;
        public decimal Line2_Attribute3;
        public string Line2_Attribute4;
        //Line 3
        public int Line3_ID;
        public decimal data_pos1;
        public decimal data_pos2;
        public decimal data_pos3;        
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string filepathRead = @"C:\Users\user1\Desktop\SampleFile.txt";
            List<someObject> somObList = new List<someObject>();
            try
            {
                FileStream fs = new FileStream(filepathRead, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fs);                               
                while (!reader.EndOfStream) 
                {                         
                    string line = reader.ReadLine();
                    if ((line.Substring(0, 4) == "1000"))
                    {
                        string[] strArrFields1 = Regex.Split(line, @"(.{6})" + "(.{14})" + "(.{20})").Where(s => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s)).ToArray();
                        someObject obj_1 = new someObject();                        
                        obj_1.Line1_ID = int.Parse(strArrFields1[0].TrimEnd(' '));
                        obj_1.Line1_Attribute1 = strArrFields1[1].TrimEnd(' ');
                        obj_1.Line1_Attribute2 = strArrFields1[2].TrimEnd(' ');
                        somObList.Add(obj_1);
                    }

                    else if ((line.Substring(0, 4) == "1001"))
                    {
                        string[] strArrFields2 = Regex.Split(line, @"(.{6})" + "(.{20})" + "(.{15})").Where(s => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s)).ToArray();                        
                        someObject obj_1 = new someObject();
                        obj_1.Line2_ID = int.Parse(strArrFields2[0].TrimEnd(' '));
                        obj_1.Line2_Attribute3 = decimal.Parse(strArrFields2[1].TrimEnd(' '));
                        obj_1.Line2_Attribute4 = strArrFields2[2].TrimEnd(' ');
                        somObList.Add(obj_1);
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        string[] strArrFields3 = Regex.Split(line, @"(.{6})" + "(.{7})" + "(.{7})" + "(.{7})").Where(s => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s)).ToArray();                        
                        someObject obj_1 = new someObject();
                        obj_1.Line3_ID = int.Parse(strArrFields3[0].TrimEnd(' '));
                        obj_1.data_pos1 = decimal.Parse(strArrFields3[1].TrimEnd(' '));
                        obj_1.data_pos2 = decimal.Parse(strArrFields3[2].TrimEnd(' '));
                        obj_1.data_pos3 = decimal.Parse(strArrFields3[3].TrimEnd(' '));                        
                        somObList.Add(obj_1);
                    }  
                } 
            }
            catch (FileNotFoundException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                Console.WriteLine("Program Exited");
                Environment.Exit(99);
            }             
            foreach (someObject o in somObList)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0},{1},{2}\n{3},{4},{5}\n{6},{7},{8},{9}",
                    o.Line1_ID, o.Line1_Attribute1, o.Line1_Attribute2, o.Line2_ID, o.Line2_Attribute3, o.Line2_Attribute4, o.Line3_ID, o.data_pos1, o.data_pos2, o.data_pos3);
            }
            somObList.Clear();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off is this how your data file looks?

```
1000 AttributeOne AttributeTwo
1001 123456.000000 AttributeFour
1002 1234.0 2345.0 3456.0 
1003 1234.0 2345.0 3456.0 
1004 1234.0 2345.0 3456.0 
1000 AttributeOne AttributeTwo  
1001 456789.000000 AttributeFour
1002 1234.0 2345.0 3456.0 
1003 1234.0 2345.0 3456.0 
1004 1234.0 2345.0 3456.0 
1000 AttributeOne AttributeTwo
1001 234567.000000 AttributeFour
1002 1234.0 2345.0 3456.0 
1003 1234.0 2345.0 3456.0 
1004 1234.0 2345.0 3456.0 
1000 AttributeOne AttributeTwo
1001 345678.000000 AttributeFour
1002 1234.0 2345.0 3456.0 
1003 1234.0 2345.0 3456.0 
1004 1234.0 2345.0 3456.0
```

Second, why are you using regular expressions to split the text? If your worrying about spacing why not normalize it.

Next you're overwriting your object in each if statement.

Here is my revised version of your code.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Linq;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace OverwritingClassObjectHelp
{
    public class someObject
    {
        //Line 1
        public int Line1_ID;
        public string Line1_Attribute1;
        public string Line1_Attribute2;

        //Line 2
        public int Line2_ID;
        public decimal Line2_Attribute3;
        public string Line2_Attribute4;

        //Line 3
        public int Line3_ID;
        public decimal data_pos1;
        public decimal data_pos2;
        public decimal data_pos3;  

        //Line 4
        public int Line4_ID;
        public decimal data_pos4;
        public decimal data_pos5;
        public decimal data_pos6; 
    }

    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            string filepathRead = @"C:\Users\C121736\Desktop\SampleFile.txt";
            List<someObject> somObList = new List<someObject>();
            try
            {
                FileStream fs = new FileStream(filepathRead, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fs);
                someObject obj_1 = null;

                while (!reader.EndOfStream) 
                {                         
                    string line = reader.ReadLine();


                    if(String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line))
                    {
                        // if line is empty do nothing
                        continue;
                    }
                    else if ((line.Substring(0, 4) == "1000"))
                    {
                        // normalize
                        line = Regex.Replace(line, @"\s+", " ");
                        string[] strArrFields = line.Split();

                        obj_1 = new someObject();                        
                        obj_1.Line1_ID = int.Parse(strArrFields[0]);
                        obj_1.Line1_Attribute1 = strArrFields[1];
                        obj_1.Line1_Attribute2 = strArrFields[2];
                    }

                    else if ((line.Substring(0, 4) == "1001"))
                    {
                        if(obj_1 == null) continue;

                        // normalize
                        line = Regex.Replace(line, @"\s+", " ");
                        string[] strArrFields = line.Split();


                        obj_1.Line2_ID = int.Parse(strArrFields[0]);
                        obj_1.Line2_Attribute3 = decimal.Parse(strArrFields[1]);
                        obj_1.Line2_Attribute4 = strArrFields[2];
                        somObList.Add(obj_1);
                    }

                    else if(line.Substring(0, 4) == "1003") 
                    {
                        if(obj_1 == null) continue;

                        // normalize
                        line = Regex.Replace(line, @"\s+", " ");
                        string[] strArrFields = line.Split();

                        obj_1.Line3_ID = int.Parse(strArrFields[0]);
                        obj_1.data_pos1 = decimal.Parse(strArrFields[1]);
                        obj_1.data_pos2 = decimal.Parse(strArrFields[2]);
                        obj_1.data_pos3 = decimal.Parse(strArrFields[3]);
                    }
                    else if(line.Substring(0, 4) == "1004")
                    {
                        if(obj_1 == null) continue;

                        // normalize
                        line = Regex.Replace(line, @"\s+", " ");
                        string[] strArrFields = line.Split();


                        obj_1.Line4_ID = int.Parse(strArrFields[0]);
                        obj_1.data_pos4 = decimal.Parse(strArrFields[1]);
                        obj_1.data_pos5 = decimal.Parse(strArrFields[2]);
                        obj_1.data_pos6 = decimal.Parse(strArrFields[3]);
                        somObList.Add(obj_1);
                        obj_1 = null;
                    }
                } 
            }
            catch (FileNotFoundException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                Console.WriteLine("Program Exited");
                Environment.Exit(99);
            }             
            foreach (someObject o in somObList)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0},{1},{2}\n{3},{4},{5}\n{6},{7},{8},{9}",
                                  o.Line1_ID, o.Line1_Attribute1, o.Line1_Attribute2, o.Line2_ID, o.Line2_Attribute3, o.Line2_Attribute4, o.Line3_ID, o.data_pos1, o.data_pos2, o.data_pos3);
            }
            somObList.Clear();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I ran the code and I understand what you did.  I was not aware of setting an object to null.

Comment: Yes, the data file as you have it is correct.  I should have been more clear that the data file has two header lines 1000 & 1001, but can have hundreds of numerica data lines, (represented by 1002 - 1004).

Comment: I can't figure out how to account for hundreds of these data lines without creating an object variable for each data item, data_pos1 - data_pos3.  If I do that I will have thousands of object variables to hold the data.  I am looking for a way to loop through each data line store the data temporarily then write to a list and still maintain the correct header information.  This is where I start overwriting the existing object.

Answer (score 0):

Here you are. This isn't exact for the specifics to your task, but I hope to lead you in an appropriate direction. I am still a new developer myself.. but maybe you'll benefit from this slightly different approach. Firstly, separate your object into a new class file. Here is mine, called `Item.cs`

```
    public class Item
    {
        public string Attribute1 { get; set; }
        public string Attribute2 { get; set; }
    }
```

And here is the program. Like I said, this won't be plug and play for you, but if you take note of how I am trying to accomplish the task you have, you may even be able to refine this further. I just use a basic text file for quick testing.. Let me know how it works out for you.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Item> myItems = new List<Item>();

        List<string> myFile = File.ReadAllLines("C:\\Path\\Values.txt").ToList();

        foreach (string value in myFile)
        {
            switch(value.Substring(0,4))
            {
                case "1001":
                    myItems.Add(MyParseMethod1(value));
                    break;
                case "1002":
                    myItems.Add(MyParseMethod2(value));
                    break;
                default:
                    myItems.Add(MyDefaultParser(value));
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    public static Item MyParseMethod1(string stringIWishtoParse)
    {
        Item myItem = new Item();

        //Parse string, set object values

        //myItem.Attribute1 = whatever portion you want from your string

        return myItem;
    }

    public static Item MyParseMethod2(string stringIWishtoParse)
    {
        Item myItem = new Item();

        //Parse string, set object values

        //myItem.Attribute1 = whatever portion you want from your string

        return myItem;
    }

    public static Item MyDefaultParser(string stringIWishtoParse)
    {
        //Follow pattern from other methods
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions.  I had not thought of using the switch case.  This makes the coding cleaner and easier to follow.